# Rotation Matrix Equivalences?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, kinematics

Given the following rotation matrix:

$$R_{BA} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2362 & 0.9412 & 0.2414\\
0.7558 & -0.3341 & 0.5631\\
0.6107 & 0.0494 & -0.7903
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is it possible to reconstruct the above transformation with only two rotations?

**Thoughts**:

My intuition tells me no simply because there is no entry that contains a $0$ value so the rotations had to have been a symmetric/asymmetric 3 rotation sequence (ie. 3-1-3, 3-2-1, etc) but how can I show this mathematically? Is it enough to simply construct a 2 rotation DCM and show there's a $0$ value? For example:

3-1 rotation rotation would lead to the DCM
$$R_{BA} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos(i) & \sin(i)\\
0 & -\sin(i) & cos(i)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega) & \sin(\omega) & 0\\
-\sin(\omega) & \cos(\omega) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega) & \sin(\omega) & 0\\
-\cos(i)\sin(\omega) & \cos(i)\cos(\omega) & \sin(i)\\
\sin(i)\sin(\omega) & -\sin(i)\cos(\omega) & \cos(i)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have constraints, such as the rotations are along $x, y, z$? If not, then you can get one rotation, or two, or any number you want.

Comment: @Andrei there are no constraints. It's simply stated $R_{BA}$ is the transformation matrix between 2 frames. How can you show you can go from A to B with one rotation? Does it have to do with how you define frames A and B?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Conversion_from_and_to_axis%E2%80%93angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear transformation corresponding to this matrix **is** a (one) rotation about the line through $(0,0,0)$ parallel to the eigenvector of the matrix.

I guess the OP might have meant Euler rotations about the coordinate axes.

Comment: other aspects of the question are in the context of Euler rotations but I'm unsure about this part. Explicitly, the question states 'Can a two rotation sequence (e.g. 1-2) achieve the transformation $R_{BA}$?'

Comment: Every rotation is a  product of two rotations: itself and $I$.